# XamDataGrid dynamic fields format poorly

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

So I have a simple window which contains only a XamDataGrid that holds preview data of a dynamic query generated at run-time...

```
public partial class DataPreview : Window
{
    public DataTable Data { get; set; }
    public DataPreview(string SQL)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
        Data = DatabaseManager.ExecuteQuery(SQL);
    }
}
```

I have databound to the datasource of the XamDataGrid...

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding Data}" ScrollingMode="Immediate">
     <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
          <igDP:FieldSettings
             AllowEdit="False"/>
     </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

Now this all works fine, the problem is the datatype of the editor in the XamDataGrid does not match the datatype of the field sometimes.  For example all numerics show with a dollar sign.  I tried to add this line...

```
EditAsType="{x:Type sys:String}"
```

Which fixed everything except actual currency amounts, which now display as xx.xxxx with no dollar sign.  All the solutions I have found online seem to edit the field's directly in the xaml, but since the fields are all dynamic this is not an option.  Is there something I can do to set the editors correctly in the xaml?  Or some routine I can do in the code to massage the data into displaying correctly from the XamDataGrid?  Can anyone share any code using XamDataGrid in a related way with all dynamic columns, but able to format them correctly based on datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor that is used for a field of a specific type can be set using the [ValueEditor.RegisterDefaultEditorForType](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2011.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v11.1~Infragistics.Windows.Editors.ValueEditor~RegisterDefaultEditorForType.html).  If the editor is the correct type and you are looking to change the mask for a given type then you could use the [XamMaskedEditor.RegisterDefaultMaskForType](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2011.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v11.1~Infragistics.Windows.Editors.XamMaskedEditor~RegisterDefaultMaskForType.html).

If you are looking to set the mask or the editor differently for different fields of the same type, then you would need to do this in code after the FieldLayout has been created.  For this you could use the [FieldLayoutInitialized event](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/2011.1/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v11.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataPresenterBase~FieldLayoutInitialized_EV.html).

Comment: How exactly do I use the ValueEditor.RegisterDefaultEditorForType method?  Do you have a link to a simple example?

Comment: There is an example in this post: http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/33674/183177.aspx#183177

Comment: I'm just a little confused what the value editor class is in this example, I cannot call this method from the XamDataGrid, it appears to be a static method for the editor itself, which makes little sense as to how this can actually solve the problem.

Comment: The XamDataGrid uses editors that derive from ValueEditor as the editors for the Fields.  The RegisterDefaultEditorForType method allows you to specify what editor to use by default for a specific type.  For example by default the XamCurrencyEditor is used for decimal and you might prefer to use the XamNumericEditor instead so you could make that change using this static method.  Note that this should be called before you set the DataSource of the grid so that it happens before the FieldLayout is initialized.